# How to hide rows based on cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

I am attempting to have cell A21 contain an integer value between 0-10 where 0 reveals no rows between 22-31, 1 reveals row 22, 2 reveals 22 and 23 and 3 reveals 22, 23, and 24, etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim GenRequire As Integer
GenRequire = Range("A21").Value

Rows("22:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Select Case GenRequire
    Case Is = 0: Rows("22:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'No Rows shown
    Case Is = 1: Rows("22:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1st Row shown
    Case Is = 2: Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-2 rows shown
    Case Is = 3: Rows("22:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-3 rows shown
    Case Is = 4: Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-4 rows shown
    Case Is = 5: Rows("22:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-5 rows shown
    Case Is = 6: Rows("22:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-6 rows shown
    Case Is = 7: Rows("22:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-7 rows shown
    Case Is = 8: Rows("22:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-8 rows shown
    Case Is = 9: Rows("22:30").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-9 rows shown
    Case Is = 10: Rows("22:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False '1-10 rows shown
End Select
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error on `Case Is = 10:`,

> Run-time error 1004:, Application-defined or object-defined error.

I have office 365 for my Excel version.

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of the code and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of code and then test it.

Comment: Not `Case Is = 0` but simply `Case 0`

Comment: @Bturner1968 I can't replicate an error with your code. Other tip - you don't need the line `Case Is = 0: Rows("22:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'No Rows shown` at all, as you are always hiding those rows one line above.

Answer (score 0):

I would make some simplifications:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim r
    r = Range("A21").Value
    If Not IsNumeric(r) Then Exit Sub
    r = Round(r, 0)
    With Rows(22)
        If r >= 1 And r < 10 Then
            Range(.Offset(0), .Offset(r - 1)).Hidden = False
            Range(.Offset(r), .Offset(9)).Hidden = True
        Else
            Range(.Offset(0), .Offset(9)).Hidden = r <> 10
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```